# python multiprocessing map returns Nones

Tags: python, numpy, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, nonetype

I am trying to speed up one of my existing application. I found this tutorial [here](https://research.wmz.ninja/articles/2018/03/on-sharing-large-arrays-when-using-pythons-multiprocessing.html) and I tried to mimic this functionality:

```
var_dict = {}

def init_worker(X,Y, X_shape):
    # Using a dictionary is not strictly necessary. You can also
    # use global variables.
    var_dict['X'] = X
    var_dict['Y'] = Y
    var_dict['X_shape'] = X_shape

def worker_func(i):
    # Simply computes the sum of the i-th row of the input matrix X
    X_np = np.frombuffer(var_dict['X']).reshape(var_dict['X_shape'])
    Y_np = np.frombuffer(var_dict['Y']).reshape(var_dict['X_shape'])
    acf = signal.correlate(X_np[i,:],Y_np[i,:],mode="full", method="fft")
    return acf

if __name__ == '__main__':
    X_shape = (5, 432000)
    # Randomly generate some data
    data1 = np.random.randn(*X_shape)
    data2 = np.random.randn(*X_shape)
    X = RawArray('d', X_shape[0] * X_shape[1])
    Y = RawArray('d', X_shape[0] * X_shape[1])
    # Wrap X as an numpy array so we can easily manipulates its data.
    X_np = np.frombuffer(X).reshape(X_shape)
    Y_np = np.frombuffer(Y).reshape(X_shape)
    # Copy data to our shared array.
    np.copyto(X_np, data1)
    np.copyto(Y_np, data2)
    # Start the process pool and do the computation.
    # Here we pass X and X_shape to the initializer of each worker.
    # (Because X_shape is not a shared variable, it will be copied to each
    # child process.)
    start = timer()
    pool = Pool(processes=2, initializer=init_worker, initargs=(X,Y, X_shape))

    result = pool.map(worker_func, range(X_shape[0]))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

    print result
    print timer() - start
```

This example is works perfectly. It actually speeds up the cross-correlation calculation.

When I tried to integrate this functionality to my Xcorrelator class it started to show some weird behavior. The memory consumption just blown up, and I have no idea how to handle this problem.

My code is rather complex but here is how I try to integrate the parallelization:

```
var_dict = {}
class Xcorrelator(object):
    .
    .
    .
    def __call__(self, w):
        self.worker_func(w)

    def init_worker(self, X,Y, X_shape):
        # Using a dictionary is not strictly necessary. You can also
        # use global variables.
        print "INIT"
        var_dict['X'] = X
        var_dict['Y'] = Y
        var_dict['X_shape'] = X_shape

    def worker_func(self,i):
        # Simply computes the sum of the i-th row of the input matrix X
        print "WORKER"
        X_np = np.frombuffer(var_dict['X']).reshape(var_dict['X_shape'])[i,:]
        Y_np = np.frombuffer(var_dict['Y']).reshape(var_dict['X_shape'])[i,:]

        ccf = signal.correlate(X_np,Y_np,mode="full", method="fft")
        return ccf

    def xcorr_parallel(self, maxlag = 600):
        rem_waveform = self._max_waveforms if self._c - self._offset > self._max_waveforms else self._c - self._offset
        shape = (rem_waveform, int((maxlag*self._sampling_rate*2) + 1))

        a, b = self.get_data_mtx()
        X_shape = a.shape

        X = RawArray('d', X_shape[0] * X_shape[1])
        Y = RawArray('d', X_shape[0] * X_shape[1])

        X_np = np.frombuffer(X).reshape(X_shape)
        Y_np = np.frombuffer(Y).reshape(X_shape)


        np.copyto(X_np, a)
        np.copyto(Y_np, b)    

        pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=2, initializer=self.init_worker, initargs=(X,Y, X_shape))
        result = pool.map(self, range(X_shape[0]))
        pool.close()
        pool.join()
        print result

        self._xcorrelations[self._offset:self._offset + rem_waveform,:] = result 
        self._offset += self._max_waveforms
```

As you see the two codes are really identical. The only difference is the second example is wrapped inside a class. 
When I call the `xcorr_parallel` method in my testing code it actually calculates the `ccf` variable but the `pool.map` function returns all `None` values in an array. Does not matter what I tried the data in the `ccf` variable always got lost.

What do I miss here? Is there any better way to wrap a parallelization mechanism inside a class? How can I overcome this problem?

Comment: You call map on `self`, not `self.worker_func`

Comment: Also: why do you try to wrap it in a class at all? Python prefers flat structure because it's interpreted. Your `worker_func` doesn't use `self`, it's a static method = it probably be a normal function. If you want to have namespaces, just move this to a different module (file), instead of encapsulating it in a class.

Comment: I overloaded the __call__ to call the worker_func. This was a inevitable move to be able to call it in the map. The second idea is actually sounds clever. I dont know why I did not think of that!